# How can i know if a perl package is suitable to install in AIX?

Tags: perl

I am having a perl package, before providing the same to my unix admin, he told me to check whether this package is suitable to install in AIX or not, Can some one please let me know how can i check that?

Regards
Hari.

Comment: A package you wrote? Or a package someone else wrote such as something from CPAN?

Comment: Depends. Is it available on CPAN? Can you try using it without installing system-wide? In fact, it is better not to mess with the system's `perl` and instead build your own, and install and test whatever modules you need.

Comment: Hi Mob, I took from CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

The Perl community provides a part of the Perl ecosystem called [cpantesters](http://www.cpantesters.org/). There are people running [smoke tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software)) on all different kinds of platforms for pretty much everything on CPAN and on many different Perl versions. [The goal of this](http://wiki.cpantesters.org/wiki/WhatIsCPANTesters) is to ensure high quality standards, even though most of the Perl world is open source and no-one gets paid for anything.

[There is a full list](http://stats.cpantesters.org/pmatrix-full.html) of all platforms that have had test reports submitted. `aix` is in there, but the list of Perls seems to be a little bit outdated. I'm not aware of a way to search distributions by platform with positive reports though.

I went through the [list of interesting stats](http://stats.cpantesters.org/interest.html) with the most reported modules and simply tried a few of them to see if `aix` is there. Turns out [Module::Runtime has one report](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Module-Runtime) on `aix` for Perl 5.19.7 (which is a developer release) which passed. You can see it [here](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Module-Runtime;os=aix;perl=5.19.7;reports=1).

You can see the top testers (as in people sending reports) for `aix` [here](http://stats.cpantesters.org/leaders/leaders-aix-all.html). Unfortunately there seems to be no way to search by reporter, so that is not of much help.

The easiest way to see if a module you want will work on your platform is by looking at its test reports. metacpan offers a handy *Testers* link that also shows averages for test reports in the left hand sidebar.

[image: screenshot of https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper]

If you decide to try building modules on your aix platform, please consider sending test reports of both passes and failures to cpantesters. I find [`cpanm-reporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus::reporter) to be a very useful tool for this.

If you have more questions about cpantesters and aspects of building stuff on this specific system, you should consider asking in *#toolchain* or *#perl-qa* on irc.perl.org, where you can talk to some of the people that built this infrastructure.

There is also [a page called `perlaix` in perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlaix.html) that might be interesting for you. It lists information about how to compile Perl itself on aix.